# How to find occurences of substring in a string

Tags: java, substring

I would like to find a substring in a string in may occur many times it may be even look like:

```
Search for: aba
Line: ababa  
Result: 2
```

I forgot what methods I should use.

Comment: *"I forgot what methods I should use."* - Well read the javadocs.  That's what they are there for!

Comment: Is your result supposed to be the last index at which the substring occurs?  The number of times the string occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String s = "ababa", key="aba";
    int limit= s.length()-key.length(), count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<=limit; i++) {
        int index = s.indexOf(key, i);
        if(index!=-1) {
            i=index+1;
            count++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use String.indexOf(String str)

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to count the number of hit of [String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) and exit when it returns -1.

Use to second parameter to "move forward" in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `indexOf` method as follows:

```
    String s = "ababa";
    String r = "aba";
    int count=0;
    int startindex = s.indexOf(r);
    while(startindex != -1)
    {
        count++;
        startindex = s.indexOf(r,startindex+1);
    }
```

The value of `count` will give you the number of occurences of the substring.

Hope it helps.